# Swift how to load a class

Tags: objective-c, swift, runtime

As we knew, when an Objective-C class was loaded the `+load` method would be called. But in Swift we don't have `+load` method.

So I tried to invested this. I added a symbol breakpoint at `call_load_methods`. In Objective-C world. this function will call all the class's `+load`. But it didn't enter this breakpoint.

So I wondering how to load in Swift. Or can you guys give me more detail a about Swift runtime or something else?

Comment: More details is: `Swift` doesn't have runtime. Welcome to `C++` club. What you trying to achieve? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, a load class method implemented in Swift is never
>   called by the runtime, rendering that recommendation an impossibility.
>   Instead, we're left to pick among second-choice options:
>
> Implement method swizzling in initialize. This can be done safely, so
>   long as you check the type at execution time and wrap the swizzling in
>   dispatch_once (which you should be doing anyway). Implement method
>   swizzling in the app delegate. Instead of adding method swizzling via
>   a class extension, simply add a method to the app delegate to be
>   executed when application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) is called.
>   Depending on the classes you're modifying, this may be sufficient and
>   should guarantee your code is executed every time.

[source](http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/)

Comment: I know swift would not call load method and how to do swizzling in Swift. I want to load how swift load a class. For example, in objc runtime, the `call_load_methods` will be called, then `call_class_loads` and `call_category_loads`. But the swift runtime is different, I want to know how different it is? How to load a class image in swift, what's the swift runtime look like ?